# wowza - play smil file at specific time

Tags: wowza, smil

We have activated the adaptive bitrate and the DVR functionality on our Wowza server. 
We have implemented a tag video functionality on both VOD and Live videos. When a tag is created on a VOD file everything works fine. We are able to play only a part of the video (tagged by the user) by specifying parameters in the URL like this:

```
http://[wowza-server-url]/blizzard_vod/mp4:dome1_stream_de037829-576e-4e0c-aa4d-8a52e21dcf86.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wowzaplaystart=1308000&wowzaplayduration=30000
```

Where the parameter **wowzaplaystart** specifies from what millisecond to start the video and the parameter **wowzaplayduration** specifies the video duration. This is how our tag works.

Problem comes when we want to tag a live event and see the tag during the event is still live.

The URL for playing a tag when the event is still live look like this:

```
http://[wowza-server-url]/blizzard_live/smil:dome2.smil/playlist.m3u8?wowzaplaystart=797000&wowzaplayduration=30000&DVR
```

During live events we play SMIL file that handles the adaptive bitrate. Because of that, the parameters that we provide no longer "cut" the video at the specified time. The DVR option is enabled and gives us the ability to play, pause, rewind the video even if it is streamed live.

Does anyone know what URL parameters to provide to the SMIL file to play it at specific time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VOD use  wowzaplaystart  and wowzaplayduration**

Adobe HDS

```
/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.f4m?wowzaplaystart=30000&wowzaplayduration=40000
```

Apple HLS

```
/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wowzaplaystart=30000&wowzaplayduration=40000
```

MPEG-DASH

```
/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.mpd?wowzaplaystart=30000&wowzaplayduration=40000
```

Smooth Streaming

```
/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/Manifest?wowzaplaystart=30000&wowzaplayduration=40000
```

**nDVR use wowzadvrplayliststart and wowzadvrplaylistduration**

Adobe HDS

```
/dvr/myStream/manifest.f4m?DVR&wowzadvrplayliststart=60000&wowzadvrplaylistduration=300000
```

Apple HLS

```
/dvr/myStream/playlist.m3u8?DVR&wowzadvrplayliststart=60000&wowzadvrplaylistduration=300000
```

MPEG-DASH

```
/dvr/myStream/manifest.mpd?DVR&wowzadvrplayliststart=60000&wowzadvrplaylistduration=300000
```

Smooth Streaming

```
/dvr/myStream/Manifest?DVR&wowzadvrplayliststart=60000&wowzadvrplaylistduration=300000
```

**SMIL**

```
<video begin="30.0" dur="40.0" src="mp4:sample.mp4" system-bitrate="450000">
```

**source**: http://blog.iiwn.live/2015/11/wowza-how-to-specify-start-time-and.html